# JSQMessagesViewController add users image

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

how to add image sender and receiver users

add add group date

[show this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSCfc.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the guidelines for how to post a good question or take a look at some other questions. You need to include more detail when asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few peices to your question. It would also be helpful if you could provide anything that you have attempted that way we know how to best help you. A broad question like this is more fully answered with the documentation on the project. Also a good hint would be checking out the develop branch of the project because it will have a more updated `swift` example.

So with the avatar you will want to make sure you define a size for the avatars. This should be called either in the init of the view or `viewDidLoad`. It should look something along these lines

```
 collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSize(width: kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault, height:kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault )
```

Those are the default values provided by the library you can also put what ever size you would like. 
Then there is a delegate method that you should override.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
```

This is where you will create and manage the image that is going to represent the avatar for that particular message. As you can see you need to return something that conformes to `JSQMessagesAvatarImageDataSource` it cannot be `nil` so you will need a default or BlankAvatar in case you do not have an image for that user.

Then I would suggest leaveraging the `JSQAvatarImageFactory`

```
JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(withUserInitials: "DL", backgroundColor: UIColor.blue, textColor: UIColor.white, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14), diameter: UInt(kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault))
```

Make sure you update the values depending on the message that it is for.

I hope that this helps you let me know if you have more questions and the more that you can provide the better.